Tarea en Python con Inputs
estoy iniciando con el aprendizaje en Python y recientemente me dejaron la siguiente tarea: "realizar un examen de 3 preguntas, donde el usuario deberá responder si o no y al final otorgarle una calificación, la califación se logra con una variable que inicia en 0 y por cada respuesta correcta incrementa en 1.
El siguiente código que realicé fue creando un diccionario "Examen" y las 3 preguntas con 3 diferentes if, pero requiero su ayuda con recomendaciones y como completar con el incremento en la califación. Gracias
    Examen = {
    'Pregunta 1': '3 > 2?',
    'Pregunta 2': '4 + 4 = 8 ?',
    'Pregunta 3': '5 + 5 = 8?'
}
Examen['Pregunta 1'] = input('3 > 2 ?\r\n')
if Examen['Pregunta 1'] == 'si':
    print('1')
else:
    print('0')
Examen['Pregunta 2'] = input('4 + 4 = 8 ?\r\n')
if Examen['Pregunta 2'] == 'si':
    print('1')
else:
    print('0')
Examen['Pregunta 3'] = input('5 + 5 = 8 ?\r\n')
if Examen['Pregunta 3'] == 'si':
    print('0')
else:
    print('1')


Tu código esta bastante bien, me parece raro que no hayas añadido un contador simple para el puntaje. Ya que es solo sumar todo lo correcto.
Apliqué unas correcciones al código, para mantener un estilo sencillo de programar. Por ejemplo, siempre analizar la respuesta correcta primero, y luego mostrar el error. Y mostrar la respuesta indicada por pregunta.
Examen = {
    'Pregunta 1': '3 > 2?',
    'Pregunta 2': '4 + 4 = 8?',
    'Pregunta 3': '5 + 5 = 8?'
}

puntaje = 0 #Contador en 0

Examen['Pregunta 1'] = input('3 > 2 ? (si/no)\r\n')
if Examen['Pregunta 1'] == 'si':
    puntaje += 1 # Agregamos un punto al contador
    print('Respuesta correcta. Tu respuesta fue:' + Examen['Pregunta 1'])
else:
    print('Respuesta incorrecta. Tu respuesta fue:' + Examen['Pregunta 1'])

Examen['Pregunta 2'] = input('4 + 4 = 8 ? (si/no)\r\n')
if Examen['Pregunta 2'] == 'si':
    puntaje += 1 # Agregamos un punto al contador
    print('Respuesta correcta. Tu respuesta fue:' + Examen['Pregunta 2'])
else:
    print('Respuesta incorrecta. Tu respuesta fue:' + Examen['Pregunta 2'])

Examen['Pregunta 3'] = input('5 + 5 = 8 ? (si/no)\r\n')
if Examen['Pregunta 3'] == 'no':
    puntaje += 1 # Agregamos un punto al contador
    print('Respuesta correcta. Tu respuesta fue:' + Examen['Pregunta 3'])
else:
    print('Respuesta incorrecta. Tu respuesta fue:' + Examen['Pregunta 3'])

print(f'Tu puntaje total es: {puntaje} de {len(Examen)}')

Ahora, este código es bastante redundante, y puede simplificarse con un for rápidamente. Pero no te deje esa solución primero, por que no se en que nivel de estudios estás. Acá el resultado.
#Ahora el diccionario, contiene la respuesta de inmediato, en el orden [pregunta,respuesta]
Examen = {
    'Pregunta 1': ('3 > 2?', 'si'),
    'Pregunta 2': ('4 + 4 = 8?', 'si'),
    'Pregunta 3': ('5 + 5 = 8?', 'no')
}

puntaje = 0 #Puntaje inicializado en 0

#Con un for, obtenemos preguntas y respuestas al recorrer el diccionario
for pregunta, respuesta_correcta in Examen.values():
    #Obtenemos las respuestas del usuario
    respuesta_usuario = input(f'{pregunta} (si/no)\r\n')
    #Realizamos el if normalmente
    if respuesta_usuario == respuesta_correcta:
        puntaje += 1
        print(f'Respuesta correcta. Tu respuesta fue: {respuesta_usuario}')
    else:
        print('Respuesta incorrecta. Tu respuesta fue: {respuesta_usuario}')
#Imprimimos el puntaje total
print(f'Tu puntaje total es: {puntaje} de {len(Examen)}')

Y el resultado obtenido sería algo:

